# I want to use index to display the View

Tags: swiftui

error
Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

When the number of indexes is the specified number, there is a view to display, but an error occurs.

Do you have a solution?

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
            if index == 1 { TestView() }
            NormalView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` part so that SwiftUI can identify each element in the array uniquely but you do not have an `array` therefore you do not need the `id` field.

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                if index == 1 { TestView() } else { EmptyView() }
                NormalView()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap block with condition in `Group`, like below (tested with Xcode 11.4)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
            Group {
                if index == 1 { TestView() }
                NormalView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```